# nHibernate and Models with Simple Arrays

Tags: nhibernate

This is my model class.

```
public class Lead
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<String> m_tags = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public int LeadId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<String> Tags { get { return m_tags; } }

}
```

Does nHibernate offer a way to represent this while maintaining the simple public API of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will work with observable collection (may need to map as IList and handle that behind the scenes) but I think you'd need to do something like this in your mapping:

```
<class name="Lead" table="Lead">
   <!-- snip -->
   <set name="Tags" table="Tags">
       <key column="TagId" />
       <element column="TagValue" type="string" />
   </set>
</class>
```

The only drawback is it does require a keyed table for your tag values.

However, I worry that the same tag can appear on multiple leads.  If this is the case, I think you will want to define tags as a many to many with an intermediate table.  That would look something like this (requiring an object for your tag):

```
<class name="Lead" table="Lead">
       <!-- snip -->
    <set name="Tags" table="LeadsXTags" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="save-update">
        <key column="LeadId"></key>
        <many-to-many class="Tag" column="TagId"></many-to-many>
    </set>
</class>
```